# Why does Python treat JSON strings differently?

Tags: python, json

```
from json import loads

jtext = {'24607': ['{"rule":"{{abnormal-key}} != \\"[]\\"","validate":[{"abnormal-key":["set flag_trace"]}]}']}
j1 = jtext
print(j1, type(j1))

j2 = j1["24607"][0]
print(j2, type(j2))

j2 = loads(j2)
j3 = j2["validate"][0]
print(j3, type(j3))

j4 = j3["abnormal-key"][0]
print(j4, type(j4))
```

To deal with Excel documents, I tried using the JSON model to transfer `str` to `dict`.
But I do not know why, in this case, `j2` should be transferred and `j3` should not.

The output:

```
{'24607': ['{"rule":"{{abnormal-key}} != \\"[]\\"","validate":[{"abnormal-key":["set flag_trace"]}]}']} <class 'dict'>
{"rule":"{{abnormal-key}} != \"[]\"","validate":[{"abnormal-key":["set flag_trace"]}]} <class 'str'>
{'abnormal-key': ['set flag_trace']} <class 'dict'>
set flag_trace <class 'str'>
```

My environment is Mac + Python 3.6 + PyCharm Community.

Comment: Your question is very unclear... What's this have to do with excel? Look at your JSON more closely.  The types all make sense

Answer (score 0):

Python is treating it as you wrote it.

`j1` is a dictionary

`j1["24607"][0]` is a string. `'24607': ['...']`.... `'{"rule":"{{abnormal-key}} != \\"[]\\"` is 1) quoted and 2) an incomplete dictionary since it's missing a bracket.

`j2["validate"][0]` is a dictionary. There's no quotes around the inner `{}`... `"validate": [  {"":[]}  ]`

`j3["abnormal-key"][0]` is a string. It's value again, has quotes, `'set flag_trace'`